# Is it considered derogatory to describe someone as "self-sufficient"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am grappling with the term ***self-sufficiency***.

The OED quotes three senses:

1a, it indicates is *not now of persons* and as the most recent example of its use is 1899, **let's forget about that**.

1b.*spec. Of persons, groups, or nations: able to provide enough of a commodity (as food, oil) to supply one's own needs, without obtaining goods from elsewhere; self-reliant, self-supporting, independent.*

Most recent example:

> 1978   Lancs. Life July 54/2   He was soon back in the Lake
>   District.., becoming self-sufficient through selling his paintings and
>   wood sculptures, doing odd jobs and growing his own food.

2. *In an unfavourable sense: Having excessive confidence in oneself, one's powers, etc.; characterized by overweening or self-conceited opinion or behaviour.*

Examples:

> 1738   tr. C. Rollin Anc. Hist. (ed. 2) I. 330   Haughty and
>   self-sufficient behaviour.
>
> 1824   R. C. Dallas Corr. Ld. Byron (1825) I. 51   Self-sufficient
>   free-thinkers and witty sophs.
>
> 1842   S. Lover Handy Andy vii,   A self-sufficient jackanapes

Sense 1a is said not to be "of persons".Ib would appear to relate to physical needs such as food, income etc. And sense 2, which is the only one relating to a person's social needs would seem derogatory.

**So is it an insult or slanderous to describe someone who lives a perfectly honourable, though slightly reclusive life, as *self-sufficient***? Can anyone quote any examples of hearing it used in a less than derogatory sense?

.

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/out-the-darkness/201303/self-sufficiency-essential-aspect-well-being ... I have to confess I've never encountered it in an emotional or social sense; but I cannot imagine that *everybody* regards independence as an affront to the community.

Comment: @StoneyB Excellent! The OED needs to move on from 1842! Perhaps I'll drop them a line.

Comment: It's usually a complement to describe someone as "self-sufficient".

Comment: @HotLicks And *self-sufficient* complements ...? :-)

Comment: OK, you got me!

Comment: @StoneyB Would you like to post that link as an answer? Without intending to be patronising, you seem to be the only person so far who has grasped the point I'm querying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and superficial Google-Booking of "self-sufficient" in recent (21st-century) works addressed to broad lay audiences suggests that when the term is applied to individuals rather than states or communities it usually—say three-quarters of the hits—has the economic sense, *OED* 1b, associated with either achieving economic independence or "living off the grid", and in this sense it's a positive goal.

Use in the sense of emotional or interpersonal independence is neither uniformly negative or uniformly positive. Psychologists and therapists tend to balance acknowledgment of the Maslowian self-actualization project with considerable critique of it:

> When you have a sense of strong self-worth, you have a healthy balance between happiness that comes from yourself and happiness that comes from your relationships. Although you’re not totally self-sufficient and happy only to be with yourself,  you’re also not dependent on people you’re in relationships with to fulfill you. —S. Renee Smith and Vivian Harte, *Self-Esteem for Dummies*

About the only domain where "self-sufficiency" has a consistent negative sense these days is Christian theology—for instance this comment on *Exodus* 32:

> Here is a description of a group of people who are self-satisfied and completely self-sufficient. In a word, the celebrants are celebrating themselves. The golden calf at the center of the festivities serves as a mirror that merely reflects back the people’s own image. —Moses Pava, *Leading With Meaning*

I did however find the negative sense raised in studies of 19th-century literary and political works, like this examination of Meredith:

> Nor is individualism the problem in itself, though as we saw with trauma it can become a key site for modern dilemmas over identity. What *is* a problem, again revealing the centrality of capitalism, is that particular form of it that can be called egoism: the reduction of the other to the status of means to an end, a pursuit of self-gratification as self-realization, and the construction of this as the self-sufficient project of life.—John Jervis, *Sympathetic Sentiments*

I am irresistibly reminded of Shaw's remark in *The Quintessence of Ibsenism* that

> A man cannot believe in others until he believes in himself; for his conviction of the equal worth of his fellows must be filled by the overflow of his conviction of his own worth.

Off the top of my head (a detailed examination could be the focus of a doctoral dissertation!), I'd suggest that *OED*'s negative sense 2 represents a traditional and conservative valuation whose underlying suppositions were repeatedly challenged by such 'advanced' 19th-century artists and philosophers as Byron, Ibsen, Nietzsche, and Shaw, leading to a largely modern positive valuation.

Comment: Very good. But historically "the age of the individual" begins well before those you mention. Napoleon was the quintessence of the *self-made man*, and the first three-quarters of the nineteenth century - the age of romanticism. The industrial entrepreneurs, Beethoven and the poets are supposed to reflect that fact! It was in the later part of the 19th century that ideas begin to mutate - viz Marx, Darwin, Freud, Schopenhauer, et al, who according to my 19th-century tutor began to prepare the world for a less-individualised vision.The Prof's favourite playwright, incidentally, was Ibsen!

Comment: @WS2 I associate Napoleon with a conservative recasting of Revolutionary communalism. I did not mean to exclude the Romantics--indeed, you could push this all the way back to Rousseau and to the *Sturm und Drang* movement. But the first generation of Romantics, although they withdrew from engagement with society, tended to seek external sources of validation in Nature and a sort of abstract Divine. It's really the second generation of Romantics who start bringing the Self into the foreground. You might take a look at Morse Peckham's *Beyond the Tragic Vision*.

Comment: As you can tell, it is some years since I visited all this. We haven't mentioned John Locke (died 65 years before Napoleon was born) and social-contract theory. An interesting paradox about Napoleon, I always think is that he was born to Corsican gentry, aristocratic enough to get a place at a military academy under the *ancien regime*, but was considered insufficiently aristocratic to be denied a commission in the Revolutionary Army! it's called having your cake and eating it, I think!

Answer (score 9):

In the U.S. at least, the unfavorable sense (2) is old-fashioned.  Being *self-sufficient* nowadays, in the U.S., is a good thing.  It's the opposite of being *needy*.

Comment: Again, like @Joel Brown, I think you are speaking of sense 1b. It is not material *self-sufficiency* which interests me. I don't believe that in the US it would be *old fashioned* to describe, let's say, a neighbour who seldom spoke, or showed any interest in anyone else,negatively as *self sufficient*.But can, I am asking, that type of *self-sufficiency* ever be a good thing?

Comment: I think that this is just what the answerers are saying -- I am a fairly well read Canadian, and have never encountered the term used in that sense either. Certainly it can apply to emotional lack of need, but it does not (IME) carry the negative connotation of the older examples. I would suggest *aloof*, *reclusive*, *self-absorbed*, *selfish*, *self-concerned* or similar if you are trying to convey this in a way that people will understand. Note that even the Victorian (and earlier) examples also include obvious pejoratives in the phrase, which make the meaning more clear.

Comment: @WS2 - There's just too much packed into your comment for me to separate things out with confidence.  Are you *looking for* a word to express an idea?  Are you trying to find out all the meanings "self-sufficient" *can* have in modern times?  Are you trying to find out what connotations people will hear when "self-sufficient" is used in a certain context?  Maybe you want more than one thing?  If you figure out what exactly you want, could you please put all your clarifications in one place (in the question!)?  I'd appreciate it because right now I'm confused.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm sorry if you are confused. Read StoneyB's answer, particularly the concluding paragraph. I've never doubted that the OED was out-of-date in this instance.

Comment: @WS2 - Your comment to this answer gave me the impression there was still something unsettled for you -- I just wasn't sure what.  But if you got the information you wanted -- all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 6):

Whether **self-sufficiency** is taken to be a positive or a negative quality will depend on the world view of the individual.  There is nothing in the usage of the term in English that implies a value judgement in and of itself.

In many cultures and world views self-sufficiency would be considered extremely admirable.  These cultures value independence, hard work and material success.

In other cultures and world views, individuality is equated with selfishness or disregard for the community.  In this context, self-sufficiency might be considered a trait to be avoided.

Comment: I think the meaning of *self-sufficiency* to which you refer here is dealt with by OED sense 1b. I am thinking more of sense 2 - where the self-sufficiency relates to a person's psychological and emotional needs. If I describe someone who sends never to socialise as *self-sufficient*, am I insulting them?

Comment: @WS2 as a native English speaker I can't think of any time I've heard this term used as an insult and it would never occur to me to think of it that way

Comment: @DarrenH Most native English speakers live in Western democracies where the [Protestant Work Ethic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestant_work_ethic) has informed our societal norms.  In many Eastern cultures the common good outweighs the individual good, and so _self-sufficiency_ might be understood to be equivalent to indifference towards community, which would certainly not be desirable in that social context.

Comment: @WS2 I think if you wanted to insult a native English speaking person for never wanting to socialise you might call them a **loner**, which often (although not exclusively) has a negative connotation.  As Darren H pointed out in his comment, you don't hear "self sufficient" being hurled as an insult in native English speaking places.

Comment: It's a bit too subtle for hurlers of insults @Joel. But I have heard it said of privileged people who take little interest in what's going on around them. And it is recognised as such by the OED, albeit with the most recent example in 1842. I've definitely heard it since then!

Answer (score 4):

**The emotional sense of *self-sufficiency* is generally, though not exclusively, used in a positive sense.**  When not positive, it’s usually either ambiguous, neutral, or as a backhanded compliment (i.e. superficially positive, but (the speaker wishes to imply) on reflection undesirable).  Straightforwardly negative use, like in the OED’s examples, seems rare.  So **it can be used negatively, but its default connotations are positive**.

Source: my own general native-speaker experience (which other answerers’ experience seems to agree with), plus searching for relevant uses in newspapers:

> If you can learn to love yourself and become emotionally self-sufficient, you'll be much more attractive to other people.
>
> — [The Guardian, *Health and Wellbeing*, Linda Blair, 17 July 2008](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2008/jul/17/healthandwellbeing.familyandrelationships)

> The heroine, and she is one, is a nervy, self-sufficient woman whose sensuous spirit has survived deep insult, betrayal and tragedy.
>
> — [New York Times Books, *Her Sense of Snow*, Brigit Frase, 10 Dec 2000](https://www.nytimes.com/books/00/12/10/reviews/001210.10fraset.html)

> It has changed her character, but then it's changed the character of all of us. Our eldest daughter has said to me that it has benefited her in a way, helped her grow up. It's helped all of the children become self-sufficient.
>
> — [The Guardian, *A mother lost and found*, Kate Hilpern and Steve Chamberlain, 18 September 2010](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2010/sep/18/encephalitis-coma-memory-loss)

The closest I could find to the OED’s negative examples:

> Codi, who narrates the story, does not imagine that she will actually be able to help her father, partly because of the hopelessness of the disease and partly because of the old man's self-sufficient and emotionally remote habits.
>
> — [New York Times Books, *In one small town, the weight of the world*, Jane Smiley, September 2 1990](http://www.nytimes.com/1990/09/02/books/in-one-small-town-the-weight-of-the-world.html?pagewanted=all)

This isn’t a conclusive, rigorous justification — but on a question like this, I think it’s about the best one can do without a fairly involved corpus analysis.

Comment: +1 But have you read @StoneyB' answer. How would you feel about *self-satisfied*?

Comment: @WS2: StoneyB’s answer seems excellent — it focuses more on explaining *why* it might be considered as positive/negative, whereas I’ve focused more on surverying/illustrating *how* it’s actually used in current practice.  //  *Self-satsisfied* has, to my ear, rather more of the negative connotations that the OED ascribes to *self-sufficient* — not quite as unambiguously negative as *smug*, but maybe somewhere between *smug* and *proud* in how much negative valence it carries.